UDP Broadcast Packet Captured by Wireshark but Not Received by Python Socket (even after binding correctly)
I'm trying to implement a UDP communication system where a sender broadcasts a packet, and a receiver (Python code) listens for it. The packet is successfully captured by Wireshark on the receiver host, but my Python socket is not receiving the broadcasted UDP packet.
I verified that the Python socket is correctly bound to the right port (37020) and IP address (0.0.0.0 for all interfaces).
Firewalls and security software are not the problem; I even tried turning off the firewall completely to rule out any potential blocking of UDP traffic on port 37020.
The socket isn't receiving the broadcasted packet, even though Wireshark can see it on the network.
Receiver:
import socket

def start_udp_server():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) as server_socket:
        
        server_socket.bind(('0.0.0.0', 37020))  # Binding to all interfaces
        print("Server listening on port 37020...")

        while True:
            message, addr = server_socket.recvfrom(4096)  # Listen for incoming packets
            print(f"Received message: {message} from {addr}")

Sender:
import socket

def send_broadcast():
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM, socket.IPPROTO_UDP) as sock:
        sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_BROADCAST, 1)
        message = "Test message"
        sock.sendto(message.encode(), ('<broadcast>', 37020))

What I’ve Checked:
Binding: The Python socket is bound to the correct address and port.
Broadcast: The socket is set to allow broadcasting.
Network: Both sender and receiver are on the same network, and the broadcast address 255.255.255.255 should work.

When I replaced <broadcast> with my local broadcast address 192.168.1.255 it worked.

Related: Sending broadcast in Python, UDP-Broadcast on all interfaces Is it possible that your sender has multiple interfaces, and you are simply not braodcasting on the interface that the receiver is listening to?

Code as is worked for me running both on the same system and failed as expected when commenting out setsockopt.

@RemyLebeau 0.0.0.0 in the receiver should listen on all interfaces.

@Barmar yes, but sendto can't broadcast on all interfaces, so it's possible that it  sends on an interface that is not connected to an interface that the receiver is listening on. That's why I ask.

@RemyLebeau The packet being sent by the sending host was captured by wireshark on the receiving host, so I think it is sending on the correct interface

I tried to send the packet to the receiving host using fixed ip address and it worked, but I won't work when I use broadcast to sent the message

@BaldStudent01 as Barmar said,  you should use your network's actual broadcast IP, not <broadcast>/255.255.255.255

@RemyLebeau Unfortunately that wasn't the solution to my problem, i used 192.168.100.255 which is my broadcast ip but the server just did not receive any packet, but when I tried the actual ip address of the server, it worked.

It is receiving broadcast message sent from the localhost though, just not receiving broadcast messages from other hosts

@RemyLebeau If you're listening on all interfaces (as 0.0.0.0 does), how can it not include the interface that it's sending on?

@Barmar as explained in the other linked questions, sendto() produces only 1 packet on 1 interface. If the sending host has multiple interfaces, there is no guarantee that a broadcast will go out on the interface that can reach the receiver. So, you should bind to the desired interface before calling sendto(), and possibly even enumerate all the local interfaces to call sendto() on each one individually.

@RemyLebeau Oops, I was assuming sender and receiver are on the same machine, as when I tested on my PC.

@Barmar even under that scenario, not all systems will deliver a broadcast to localhost.

@RemyLebeau the sending host that I am testing on right now is a bridged virtual machine that only has 1 interface and it is sending on that interface. I can capture the sent packet on wireshark but somehow it is not being received on the application layer. The sending vm has no problem pinging the receiving host

@BaldStudent01 the code shown is fine, provided a proper broadcast IP is used. If the packet is not being delivered to the application, then that sounds like a networking issue, not a coding issue. Try asking on [sf] or Network Engineering.

@RemyLebeau Alright thank you very much
